# Show that $\lim_{z\to 0}|z|^{\sqrt 2}f(z)=0$ in $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $f$ be analytic in $\mathbb D\setminus\{0\}$ and unbounded near $z=0$. If the function $|z|^{\sqrt 2}f(z)$ is bounded at $z=0$ then show that $$\lim_{z\to 0}|z|^{\sqrt 2}f(z)=0\text{  &  }\lim_{z\to 0}|z|^{\sqrt 2/2}f(z)=\infty.$$where , $\mathbb D=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\}.$

Since, the function $|z|^{\sqrt 2}f(z)$ is bounded at $z=0$ so, it has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and so, $\lim_{z\to 0}z.|z|^{\sqrt 2}f(z)=0$. From here , how I can show the required limit ?

Comment: $|z|^{\sqrt 2}f(z)$ is not analytic, so why do you think it has a removable singularity?

Answer (score 1):

The order of a singularity at a point $a$ is defined as the smallest value $\alpha\geq 0$ such that
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow a} |z-a|^\alpha |f(z)| = 0.$$  For functions analytic on a punctured disc about $a$, it turns out that either there is no $\alpha$ satisfying this limit (and in particular, no minimum), or that the minimum exists and takes a non-negative integer value.

The hypothesis on the bound of $|z|^{\sqrt{2}}f(z)$ at $z=0$ shows that the order of the singularity is at most one, and the hypothesis that $f$ is unbounded at $z=0$ shows that the order is at least one.

Comment: Not clear to me...

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Which part?

Comment: @  zibadawa timmy ) The first statement..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 This definition and theorem about the order of singularities of analytic functions is a standard result in complex analysis.  If your class has not yet covered it, then my solution, while accurate, will not be adequate for you.  Have you considered zhw.'s sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $z^2f(z)$ is analytic in some $\{0<|z|<r\},$ and from the given information, $z^2f(z) \to 0$ at $0.$ In particular $z^2f(z)$ is bounded in this domain. Hence it has a removable singularity at $0.$ Thus $z^2f(z) = \sum a_nz^n $ in this domain. Think about the first few of the coefficients $a_n.$